# How to display Bootstrap stylesheets with a .cfm extention in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, internet-explorer-9

Why does IE9 lose all stylesheets when using a .cfm file name?

I'm testing a basic example template from Bootstrap (http://surgenia.com/instal/temp.cfm)

It works fine with FF and Chrome or even just changing temp file to temp.htm

Comment: Are your css files included? Your page is still HTML when it's returned from the server.

Comment: They are included by link tags  <link href="http://surgenia.com/instal/temp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  Also just tried <cfinclude template="temp.css">, if thats what you meant?  The page works fine in FF or chrome.

Comment: You can try it at http://surgenia.com/instal/temp.cfm.  or temp.htm (which works fine...even though they are the same file).

Comment: i believe you need `http://` with your css links

Comment: when I visit that link it works fine.

Comment: Correct this error at the bottom of your .cfm and see if that helps `<script src="http://http://surgenia.com/instal/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Antony.  I removed the double http.  Still doesn't fix problem though.  I had just gone through to make all links absolute.  I'm testing with explorer 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't to do with the extension - your temp.cfm and temp.htm files have different content.

Specifically, the temp.cfm file has a "store session variables" comment before the doctype, throwing IE into Quirks Mode. (Your temp.htm file does not have this comment, and is not in Quirks Mode.)

You can see this is what's happening by opening Developer Tools (press F12) - you will see in the HTML view that the doctype declaration is commented out, and the Document Mode in the top right of the window is "Quirks".

Change the mode to "Internet Explorer 9 standards" and the page displays the same as the temp.htm one. Removing the comment which is outputting will also have the same effect of not putting IE into quirks mode, (or change it to a CFML comment, as it's intended to be, but it looks unnecessary so removing it probably is best).

You might also want to consider placing `<cfcontent reset type="text/html" />` immediately before any doctype declarations, to help avoid similar problems (by resetting the output buffer before output is started).